# How come these 2 implementations of dfs give different results?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

This one gives the correct result:

```
def binaryTree(root):
    paths = []

    def dfs(root, path=""):
        if root:
            if path != "":
                path += "->"
            path += str(root.val)
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                paths.append(path)
            dfs(root.left, path)
            dfs(root.right, path)

    dfs(root)
    return paths # gives ['1->2->4', '1->2->5', '1->3']
```

And in this one the list of path keeps growing:

```
def binaryTree2(root):
    paths = []

    def dfs(root, path=[]):
        if root:
            path.append(root.val)
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                paths.append("->".join(map(str, path)))
            dfs(root.left, path)
            dfs(root.right, path)

    dfs(root)
    return paths # gives ['1->2->4', '1->2->4->5', '1->2->4->5->3']
```

The tree is like this: `<1, <2, <4, None, None>, <5, None, None>>, <3, None, None>>`

The only difference is that in one I concatenate strings and in the other I append to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the first implementation: All `path += ...` statements essentially create a new string and have `path` point to it.

As for the second implementation you have a *single* list that is passed around all the time. You should pop back the node right before dfs returns.

```py
def binaryTree2(root):
    paths = []

    def dfs(root, path=[]):
        if root:
            path.append(root.val)
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                paths.append("->".join(map(str, path)))
            dfs(root.left, path)
            dfs(root.right, path)
            path.pop() # this clears your stack as your functions return

    dfs(root)
    return paths
```

Edit: Python strings are immutable - i.e. once created, they can't be modified.

```py
# below line essentially creates a pointer,
# and a string object that `path` points to.
path = "huhu"

# this creates another string object `huhu123`.
# So at this point we have 3 strings objects,
# "123", "huhu" and "huhu123". And a pointer `path` if you will.
# `path` points to "huhu123"
path += "123"
```

If we had more innocent objects instead of strings, once they are left with no references, they'd be garbage collected. Strings get special treatment, in our case all 3 of them are *interned*.

Comment: I don't understand why `path += s` creates a new string.

Comment: Because strings in python are immutable. Let me elaborate in the answer ^